# Is there a command to run executable files from git?

Tags: command-line, git-bash, git

I'm trying to run files/open files from the command line....git.  I'm still having problems just getting sublime to launch right.  It does open but it won't open as administrator.  Also, as I'm browsing files, directories, and commits, it would be nice to be able to open these files from the command line for some quick review.  HOW ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an executable file, say runme.exe, you should be able to run that file with:

```
$ ./runme.exe
```

As for opening files, you should be able to open up a file with a text editor such as vi. You could try:

```
$ vi openme.txt
```

to open the file openme.txt. If you just want to read the file you can do

```
$ cat openme.txt
```

or

```
$ less openme.txt
```

to scroll through the file.

You can also use another text editor from the command line (really any of your choice), but I would recommend vim or emacs if you're just doing a quick review.